# I have a ViewPager which contains multiple ListViews, where do I listen for an item being clicked?

Tags: android, listview, click, android-viewpager, onitemclick

I have an activity which contains classes for my list adapter and my view pager adapter as well as your standard activity functions.

The result is the ability to swipe through multiple lists.

I'm not sure where to listen for an item click. In the main activity? In the list adapter? view pager adapter? how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `ListView` you have to set an `OnItemClickListener` within your `ViewPagerAdapter`. You can either create a separate listener for each `ListView`, or give each `ListView` a tag and use a single listener that checks the tag and responds accordingly.

Comment: @benwiz I am working on similar kind of thing in which I need to show multiple list views inside an activity and also viewpager to swipe through pages. I have tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708133/multiple-listview-in-a-activity-programatically-populated-from-database. Can u guide me?