# Multiple listview in a activity programatically populated from database

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created listviews programatically and added them into horizontal scrollview as shon in image
[image]

And My Activity

```
    package com.example.dynamiclistviewtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.Orientation;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    //LinearLayout llListView;
    LinearLayout llMain;
    ListView[] listView;
    private HorizontalScrollView scrollListView;
    private int counter = 0; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scrollListView = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollListView);
        //llListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llListView);
        llMain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llMain);
        listView = new ListView[5];

        //Onclick listener
        Button.OnClickListener btnpayClick = new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.setText("Button "+counter);
            }

        };

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();

        for (int pages = 0; pages <10 ; pages++) {
            LinearLayout llViewHolder = new LinearLayout(this);
            llViewHolder.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            llViewHolder.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f));
            for (int page_row = 0; page_row < 2; page_row++) {
                LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
                row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f));
                llViewHolder.addView(row);
                for (int sale = 0; sale< 3; sale++) {
                    View item = inflator.inflate(R.layout.view_inflate, null);
                    ListView listofItems = (ListView) item.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                    Button btnpay = (Button)item.findViewById(R.id.btnpay);
                    btnpay.setOnClickListener(btnpayClick);
                    btnpay.setText("pay "+sale);
                    LayoutParams lpll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,300,1.0f);
                    lpll.setMargins(30, 10, 10, 10);
                    listofItems.setLayoutParams(lpll);
                    String[] data = new String[]{"Ashok","Shaishavi","jatin","Akansha","Aditi","Bhavesh","Rajesh","Roshni","Heema"};
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapater = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
                    listofItems.setAdapter(arrAdapater);

                    /*listView[i] = new ListView(this);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,100);
                    lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    listView[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
                    listView[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                    llListView.addView(listView[i]);*/

                    row.addView(item);
                }

                //listView[3].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            llMain.addView(llViewHolder);
        }



    }




}
```

and xml layout  file activity_main  which contains horizontal scrollview and a linear layout to hold all views and code for this layout file as below:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <!--<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>-->

</LinearLayout>
```

and view that I have inflated from view_inflate.xml file it's code is as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="540dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/paybtn_lgreen" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnpay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Payment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to populate all listviews that I have added from local database sqlite, How can I achieve   this?

Comment: Not getting your question. You want to add data in all these listviews from a database. Is that what you desire?

Comment: yes I want to populate all listviews from my sqlite database and also want click event of all buttons.

Comment: Then what stops you from using a database, pushing your values in that and fetching it back in the ArrayList<ArrayList<Hashmap....> arr, and use it as you were? A tutorial - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: This is simple one listview I want to populate multiple at a time.would please help me how can use above in my code. Where and how I select and populate data in above code that creates UI.

Comment: The tutorial was fairly simple. Just read it, and start from point 4.3, and think 'comments' they are putting in their databases, replace them with people of your application. And everything falls into place. Give it a try atleast.